# Interfacing and Game Architecture in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript, interface, abstract

I am in the midst of creating the architecture for my new Point and Click game in the Starling framework. It is set to be big in size, so I am trying to make sure to use best Object Oriented practises to ensure I do not A) Repeat the same methods. B) Keep it sustainable and clean.

I was unaware of Interfacing as a way to contract all classes. To keep everything consistent and to ensure that sub classes have the methods to function correctly. Let us look at an example of a player class i have created.

```
public interface IPlayer {
   function changeDirection():void;
   function walkToPosition():void;
   function pickUpItem():void;
}

class AbstractPlayer extends Sprite implements IPlayer {
   public function changeDirection():void {}
   protected function walkToPosition():void {}
   protected function pickUpItem():void {}

}

class Player extends AbstractPlayer {
   override protected function walkToPosition():void {}
   override protected function pickUpItem():void {}
}
```

I am aware that AS3 Does not support Abstract Classes natively. But I choose to have it in this form as it makes sense to. What I do not understand is why the interfaces only support public methods. Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of having an interface; so you know what methods are needed for a player. Declaring only the public functions of the player class seems like a half job.

A verbose explanation of this concept and perhaps a more advanced solution to how this could be structured would be of great benefit.

Many Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface is a collection of method declarations that **allows unrelated objects** to communicate with one another.Hence public access control identifiers for implemented methods.In a typical interactive context often a need arises to modify or control behavior of an object in question externally.In such a case, behavior-control may ideally be accomplished through an interface.Obliviously only methods put into a public namespace are accessible externally.Bearing in mind that attributes of an object should not be be directly modified by external code but only through an interface is good practice of **Object Oriented Design**. Assuming that a need arises of an object to have more than one point of access control(behavior control); one for external purposes and the other for  internal purposes respectively, then putting all behavior in one interface defeats the objective.The following may help to achieve the objective(**because you said it's big in size**).

- Put behavior in an interface you think should be accessible externally.
- Define Mediator to encapsulate view-code-mediation:-listen for user triggered events, update view send notifications to other tiers of the application.
- Define Model for data purposes.
- Define executable commands to be called within your application.

See if you can promote as much lose coupling as possible among the tiers.The goal is to write as much less code as possible and not boiler-plate in nature.I recommend that you use a framework such as **robotlegs** if really your project is that big.The framework will take  care of dependency injection and along the way lift off the burden of writing boiler-plate code.

I Hope the foregoing helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The interface is acting as an outline of required members to be implemented in the classes using said interface. Therefore the interface methods never being called directly and only being used in the classes implementing them require no access modifiers.

Now you're correct AS3 does not support abstract classes, BUT there is a way to implement an "abstract" class AS3 as per the design. So here is what that might look like with your code:

```
public interface IPlayer
{
    function init():void;
    function changeDirection():void;
    function walkToPosition():void;
    function pickUpItem():void;
}

public class AbstractPlayer extends Sprite implements IPlayer
{
    public function AbstractPlayer() {
        init();
    }

    protected function init():void {
        throw new IllegalOperationError( "Abstract method, must be overridden in subclass" );
    }

    public function changeDirection():void {}

    protected function walkToPosition():void {}

    protected function pickUpItem():void {}
}

public class Player extends AbstractPlayer
{
    public function Player() {
        super();
    }

    override protected function init():void {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Abstract classes having method implementation by default will require subclasses to override these methods ( see `init()` and error thrown ) keeping strict usage of the parent class method and members.

This is the basic abstract class design for AS3. This is also the begining to a Factory Method pattern which you can read more on here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/ora_as3_design_patterns.html

Now the more reusable design for this might be to generalize your class names a bit more, perhaps something more like this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    function init():void;
    function changeDirection():void;
    function walkToPosition():void;
}
```

This would be assuming that more game objects other than your `Player` class will have use of the methods in the `IEntity` interface.

Now your `Player` class can become a new object of type Entity:

```
public class Entity extends Sprite implements IEntity
{
    public function Entity() {
        init();
    }

    protected function init():void {
        throw new IllegalOperationError( "Abstract method, must be overridden in subclass" );
    }

    public function changeDirection():void {}

    protected function walkToPosition():void {}

    protected function pickUpItem():void {}
}
```

Now in regards to the design, since abstract classes are just a tool like any other there are many different designs to take using it and it really depends on your project. I would recommend sifting through the aforementioned link to the "Factory Method" pattern and some of the other designs to see what fits your needs.

Comment: Excellent thanks for the insight. I know that Factory Pattern is well known implementation for games. Will look into further. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

An interface defines the way other classes interact with a specific implementation of that interface. Other classes cannot call implementation's private methods directly - there's no need for the interface to define them.

Let's say we have two subclasses of `AbstractPlayer`: `Player` and `AIPlayer`. The `Player` class would probably include methods to listen for specific input events and to respond to them accordingly, like `onKeyUp` or `onMouseClick`, which should be private: there's no need to external classes to know how the player is controlled. The `AIPlayer` on the other hand is controlled by some strategies you define in your code, therefore instead of listening to user's input, it should keep track of `Player`'s actions and react accordingly. This class does not need `onKeyUp` or `onMouseClick` methods, so why put them in interface?